# Get term name by term id

Tags: drupal-6

I have a term `product` with term *id* `123`.

How can I use the term *id* `123` to get the term name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term/5

Comment: Since the question is tagged drupal-6 here the direct link to the d6-api: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term/6 (which features a second parameter)

Answer (score 0):

place this function in template file

```
function getTermsName($taxnomyid){
$terms =  taxonomy_get_term($taxnomyid);
$termsname = $terms->name;
return $termsname;
}
```

and use `<?php echo getTermsName($taxnomyid); ?>` to print term name wherever you want 
`$taxonomyid` is your term id